# No BOOT1 pin on ST MCU

Tags: stm32

I watched [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZUXuk2zFHfs) where ST itself states that `BOOT0` and `BOOT1` pins are used to select the memmory that MCU starts reading after the boot :

```
┌───┬───────┬────────────┬────────────────────────────────────┐
│   │ BOOT0 │   BOOT1    │   After reset MCU starts reading   │
├───┼───────┼────────────┼────────────────────────────────────┤
│ A │     0 │ irrelevant │ FLASH                              │
│ B │     1 │ 0          │ bootloader (inside system memmory) │
│ C │     1 │ 1          │ RAM                                │
└───┴───────┴────────────┴────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Also the offical ST's [bootloader guide](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/application_note/b9/9b/16/3a/12/1e/40/0c/CD00167594.pdf/files/CD00167594.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00167594.pdf#cha) *(chapter 4.1, table 2, pattern 1)* mentions `BOOT0` and `BOOT1`.

I check the [documentation for ST's MCU](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/stm32f030rc.pdf) and there is no slightest trace of the `BOOT1` pin! WTF?

Where is `BOOT1` pin?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not all STM32 MCUs have a pin called BOOT1. Some do, some don't. Either way BOOT1 is usually shared with a GPIO pin so it would not be a separate pin.

Even the bootloader guide should indicate that the specfic MCU you are using has no BOOT1 pin.

Since you are using F030 chip, bootloader is triggered by Pattern 2, not Pattern 1 like you expect.

Comment: Pattern 2 mentions `nBoot1` which also can't be found (even <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> finds nothing) in the entire datasheet of that MCU... What now? It is a dead end either way.

Comment: The nBOOT1 is a configuration bit in flash memory. And you are looking the information in the wrong place, it will not be in the datasheet, but in the reference manual.

Comment: I will search the reference manual and check if I find anything more there.

Comment: So how do a person configure `nBOOT1` if it is just a bit? You say it is in FLASH, so if I change it at any time it will keep it's value after reset as well?

Comment: You can program it with any programming tool that allows writing of the user configuration bits and it will keep its value until changed. But why would you want to change it at any time, what are you trying to do or achieve? It only selects if the MCU boots to factory bootloader or SRAM, if you don't boot from flash.

Comment: I am writing my own programmer tool. So I need to be able to choose between multiple boot modes in the programmer. So for STM32F0103xx family it is easy. I can set `BOOT0` and `BOOT1` pins and woila, it boots in the bootloader. But for family STM32F030RC I know hoe to set `BOOT0`, but I don't understand, how I can set `nBOOT1` bit (to choose the boot mode) **before** I am even able to contact the bootloader? I am currently reading this: https://cybergibbons.com/hardware-hacking/reading-and-writing-firmware-on-an-stm32-using-the-serial-bootloader/

Comment: Programming over which interface? Well if you want to go to factory bootloader, you don't need to touch nBoot1 at all. You can download code to SRAM and jump to execute SRAM. If you set nBoot1 to 1, you can never boot factory bootloader as MCU either boots from SRAM or your flash area, so your flash or custom bootloader needs to be able to load data to SRAM for execution at next boot.

Comment: From the posted link (in the comments) I found out that `nBOOT1` is `1`  by default. So the problem is solved. Thank you.